# Devise form : <input name="email"/> instead of name"user[email]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, devise, autofill, warden

autofill on Chrome on iOs is not working when there is `<input name="user[email]"/>`, only when there is `<input name="email"/>`

Is there a way to post { email: 'xx' }, instead of { user: { email: 'xx' } } with devise?

So I tried to generate `Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` in order to understand https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb (`def create`) but I couldn't. I think I have to modify one or two lines on sessionscontroller#create but I don't understand warden.authenticate!

I think this is what warden call 'default_scope', I tried `auth_option.merge({scope: :default})` but not working

maybe modifying `devise_parameter_sanitizer`, something like `.merge({user:{email:params[:email], password:params[:password]})`, i don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user the `autocomplete: "email"` option in the field.

e.g. in SimpleForm:

```
<%=f.input :email, input_html: { autocomplete: 'email' } %>
```

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values